# c++11 typedef function pointer with trailing return type

Tags: c++11, function-pointers, typedef, trailing-return-type

I have been trying to clean up an inherited code base. It makes extensive use of template functions that include a trailing return type. It also includes a lot of function pointers to non-templated, non-member functions. During the clean up I discovered that code equivalent to the following works under Visual Studio 2013:

```
#define function typedef auto

function Kernel (int, int) -> int;

struct Transform
{
    Kernel* kernel;
    char*   description;
};

Transform add_transform { add, "add" };
```

Is this typedef valid in the C++11 standard?

While I personally avoid #defines like the plague (especially when used to create a new language feature like these 'functions'), given the prevalence of trailing return types in the project the team feels this would make the code base significantly more readable.

Comment: `typedef auto Kernel(int, int) -> int;` is legal. Enjoy trying to use `std::function` with that macro, though.

Comment: I couldn't agree more - unfortunately my team disagrees! I was hoping that it would be compiler dependent so that I could discourage them from using it.

Comment: `using Kernel = int(int, int);` is more readable, and actually valid C++ syntax.

Comment: `using Kernel = auto(int, int) -> int;` is also valid, but at that point you can see how silly this is.

Comment: The `#define` looks more like a prank gone wrong.

Comment: It gets worse! We use Visual Assist and someone has suggested changing the macro color scheme to match classes/structs. I mainly code in haskell so I understand the appeal of treating functions as first class citizens but this is ridiculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trailing return type syntax is new in C++11, and it is valid wherever you can write a function type. `auto <function>(<parameters>) -> <result>` is simply a fancy way of writing `<result> <function>(<parameters>)` (with the benefit that `<result>` can refer to `<parameters>`).

This means `typedef auto Kernel (int, int) -> int;` is perfectly valid, and means exactly the same thing as `typedef int Kernel (int, int);`. That `Kernel` typedef can then be be used in declarations of functions, or of pointers to functions.

Comment: Thank you for confirming it is legal in c++11. I actually quite like the typedef auto ... form as it appeals to my maths background. That said, I hate the #define and I was hoping this would not be the case.

Answer (score 3):

It can be tempting to re-invent C++ syntax using macros. You might come up with something cool like this and think "wow that's so much more clear".

The most fundamental problem with this approach is that it's only more readable to the guy inventing the macro, or if you don't know C++ well enough. If you are perfectly comfortable understanding what `typedef auto fn(int) -> int` means, then you will no longer find your macro useful at all. The syntax is already clear enough.

To compound things, you introduce all the myriad of problems with macros. You are hijacking the `function` symbol name across the board - regardless of scope. Now you can no longer use `std::function`. Not only can you not use it, but it's going to throw some nasty compiler errors that are not descriptive at all. The compiler will be trying to parse `std::typedef auto` which is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

It's valid because `auto(int, int) -> int;` is a function declarator except that it's missing a name. The name, `Kernel`, is the identifier used by the `typedef` specifier to create the *type-name*. Since a *trailing-return-type* is present, `auto` is replaced by `int` and it becomes `int(int, int)`. If you want to convince your team that it's futile, consider the ways you can achieve the same syntax:

```
using Kernel = int(int, int);
using Kernel = auto(int, int) -> int;
typedef auto Kernel(int, int) -> int;
```

These are all semantically equivalent and avoids using a macro.